# Problem when trying to remove a node in a tree

Tags: c, tree

I have a binary tree. I'm trying to delete one of the node and all of his "children". But, my function deletes just the children and  the "father" is still remaining there. whats wrong with my code? why the "father" isnt Deleted??

```
BinTree* familyGotVaccin(BinTree* root)
{
    int isFather = 1;
    BinTree* father = NULL;
    BinTree* gotVaccinated = NULL;
    int ID;
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    printf("Who got vaccinated (ID)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &ID);
    if (checkIfExist(root, ID) == 0)
    {
        printf("There is no ID %d\n", ID);
        return root;
    }
    if (root->ID == ID)
    {
        gotVaccinated = root;
        isFather=0;
    }
    else
    {
        father = findNode(root, ID);
        if (father == NULL)
            return root;
        if (father->left != NULL && father->left->ID == ID)
            gotVaccinated = father->left;
        if (father->middle != NULL && father->middle->ID == ID)
            gotVaccinated = father->middle;
        if (father->right != NULL && father->right->ID == ID)
            gotVaccinated = father->right;
    }
        gotVaccinated=deleteVaccinated(gotVaccinated);
        free(gotVaccinated);
        if (isFather == 0)
            root = NULL;
        return root;
    
}




BinTree* deleteVaccinated(BinTree* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (root->left == NULL && root->middle == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ID: %d Survived!\n", root->name, root->ID);
        root = NULL;
        free(root);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left=deleteVaccinated(root->left);
    if (root->middle != NULL)
        root->middle=deleteVaccinated(root->middle);
    if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right=deleteVaccinated(root->right);
    printf("%s ID: %d Survived!\n", root->name, root->ID);
    root = NULL;
    free(root);
    return NULL;

}
```

Comment: gotVaccinated() return's NULL, and then you free that NULL.. Other than that, what do you mean by "still reamaining there".. Does the "father" still there and has a value? or is he just NULL?

Comment: I mean by "still reamaining there" that the "father" still there and has a value

Comment: You say `father = findNode(root, ID);`, and then check the left, right and middle of that node for ID.. findNode does not return you the node with that ID already?

Comment: FindNode returns the father of the node with that id.

Comment: Because  i need both father and the son with the given id

Comment: Okay after those 3 if-checks, `gotVaccinated ` is either `father->left`, `father->right`, or `father->middle`. For the example lets say its `father->left`. You send it to `deleteVaccinated`, which delete all of `father->left` nodes, and then you delete `father->left` itself, and return the root. What is the problem? You never touched the original father (which is `root`).. Why you expect it to change?